# JS Youtube player on android in webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, youtube

I need to run a Youtube player inside my Android app and control it from the app (play button, know when the movie ended...) .
I try to use a webview as my solution but failed:
When I try to use the new iframe API (http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/iframe_api_reference.html#Examples) the movie won’t play and I get this error:
Web Console(21500): Unable to post message to http://www.youtube.com. Recipient has origin file://.

When I try to use the JavaScript API (http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html) the movie is playing but trying to call JS function on the player failed. I get this error:
E/Web Console(21722): Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'loadVideoById' at file:///android_asset/demo1.html:16

So I can play the movie but can’t control the player.

Any Idea how to play Youtube movies and control the player on Android? (Code samples will be appreciate :) )

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: play using RTSP and videoview